# Trouble adding folder into plex

Tags: plex

Newbie here, I really have tried searching for a solution, but the responses are for older versions and just dont work with my issue.  Using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.  Installed plex media server.  When I attempt to add a media folder (/home/derek/desktop/TV) it doesnt show up.  I navigate to /home/derek and there are no subfolders in plex.  I know its permission related, but I had trouble running the 755 command on the folder because it said it wasnt there.  I really want to improve my skills with Ubuntu, but just keep hitting a wall.

Comment: found the answer at PLEX.  Sorry for asking a dumb question.  https://support.plex.tv/articles/200288596-linux-permissions-guide/

Comment: Aside from the Plex guide you mentioned, you can also use the Snap version of Plex - it uses root's permissions to access library files, so it basically "cuts the knot" on any system permission issues.